# Snap.svg: casting a shadow from a masked shape

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to make a material-ish design wherein there's two layers with a shadow in between. I figured the simplest way to do this would be to draw the bottom layer directly (simply a covering rectangle for the background) and then draw another rectangle, using a mask, to draw the content of the image. This rectangle should be casting a shadow, but I believe that due to the shadow being outside the mask, it is not being rendered. How can I make it render?

Codepen demonstration: https://codepen.io/Krakob/pen/OjqNKP (on site snippet doesn't seem to be loading snap properly)

Used code:

```js
function logo(conf) {
  if (typeof conf === 'undefined') {
    var ch = 0.5; // Hue
    var cs = 0.4; // Saturation
    var cl = 0.5; // Luminosity

    conf = {
      text: ':^(',
      c_fg: Snap.hsl(ch, cs, cl),
      c_bg: Snap.hsl(ch, cs * 0.9, cl * 0.4),
      border: 10,
      tri_height: 20
    }
  };

  var canvas = Snap(100, 100);
  var foregr = Snap(100, 100);

  // Cover up the back of the canvas
  canvas.rect(0, 0, 100, 100).attr('fill', conf.c_bg);

  // Fill up the foreground with white
  foregr.rect(0, 0, 100, 100).attr('fill', 'white');

  // Subtract a circle
  foregr.circle(50, 50, 50 - conf.border).attr('fill', 'black');

  // Left triangle
  foregr.polygon([
    0, 50 - conf.tri_height / 2,
    0, 50 + conf.tri_height / 2,
    conf.tri_height, 50
  ]).attr({
    fill: 'white',
  });

  // Top triangle
  foregr.polygon([
    50 - conf.tri_height / 2, 0,
    50 + conf.tri_height / 2, 0,
    50, conf.tri_height
  ]).attr({
    fill: 'white',
  })

  foregr.text(50, 50, conf.text).attr({
    fill: 'white',
    'text-anchor': 'middle',
    'alignment-baseline': 'middle',
    'font-size': '2em',
    'font-family': 'Quicksand',
  });

  var shadow = canvas.filter(Snap.filter.shadow(2.5, 2.5, 0, 'red', 1));

  canvas.rect(0, 0, 100, 100).attr({
    fill: conf.c_fg,
    mask: foregr,
    filter: shadow
  })

  return canvas;
}

logo();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>:^(</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/master/dist/snap.svg.js"></script>
  <script src="my.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you probably need to get a working fiddle or bin for people to check further.

Comment: I linked a codepen. Is it not working?